# how to pass invalid password function

Tags: passwords, invalidoperationexception

I am using this function to show me invalid password when the user password does not matches but it always open encrypt decrypt function for me!

char username[50], pword[50];
struct user usr;

```
        printf("\nEnter your username:\t");
        takeinput(usr.username);
        printf("Enter your password:\t");
        takepassword();

        fp = fopen("Users.dat", "r");
        while (fread(&usr, sizeof(struct user), 1, fp))
        {
            if (strcmp(usr.username, username))
            {
                if (strcmp(usr.password, pword))
                {
                    system("cls");
                    printf("\n\t\t\t\t\t\tWelcome\n");
                    encrypt_decrypt();
                }
                else if ((!strcmp(usr.password, pword)))
                // if password is not matching with user password
                {
                    printf("\n\nInvalid Password!");
                }
               usrFound = 1;  
            }

           
        }
        if (!usrFound)
        {
            printf("\n\nUser is not registered!");
        }

        fclose(fp);
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a safe approach to store passwords, especially if it is only used to verify that a user knows the password. Instead of encryption, which can encrypt and decrypt a password, you should have a look at password-hash functions like Argon2, BCrypt or PBKDF2. Those functions generate an irreversible hash value, which can be used to check the password, but not to get the original password back.